# Neo4j Cypher: find groups of A nodes related to B nodes sharing a same property values

Tags: neo4j, compare, cypher

I have two types of nodes labelled A and B and related by a relationship R

I try to get the groups of A nodes that exactly relates to B nodes with the same property value

So, the example below should return two groups: (a2, a5) and (a3, a4)

```
 (A)-->(B) | B.Property
------------------------
  a1-->b1  |  p1
  a1-->b2  |  p2
  a1-->b3  |  p3
  a2-->b4  |  p4
  a3-->b5  |  p2
  a3-->b6  |  p4
  a4-->b7  |  p2
  a4-->b8  |  p4
  a5-->b9  |  p4
  a6-->b10 |  p1
  a7-->b11 |  p3
  a7-->b12 |  p5
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your example dataset using the following command:

```
CREATE
  (a1:A {name:'a1'}),
  (a2:A {name:'a2'}),
  (a3:A {name:'a3'}),
  (a4:A {name:'a4'}),
  (a5:A {name:'a5'}),
  (a6:A {name:'a6'}),
  (a7:A {name:'a7'}),
  (a1)-[:R]->(b1:B {name: 'b1', property: 'p1'}),
  (a1)-[:R]->(b2:B {name: 'b2', property: 'p2'}),
  (a1)-[:R]->(b3:B {name: 'b3', property: 'p3'}),
  (a2)-[:R]->(b4:B {name: 'b4', property: 'p4'}),
  (a3)-[:R]->(b5:B {name: 'b5', property: 'p2'}),
  (a3)-[:R]->(b6:B {name: 'b6', property: 'p4'}),
  (a4)-[:R]->(b7:B {name: 'b7', property: 'p2'}),
  (a4)-[:R]->(b8:B {name: 'b8', property: 'p4'}),
  (a5)-[:R]->(b9:B {name: 'b9', property: 'p4'}),
  (a6)-[:R]->(b10:B {name: 'b10', property: 'p1'}),
  (a7)-[:R]->(b11:B {name: 'b11', property: 'p3'}),
  (a7)-[:R]->(b12:B {name: 'b12', property: 'p5'})
```

This query returns the desired pairs:

```
MATCH (a1:A)-[:R]->(b1:B) // 1
WITH *
ORDER BY ID(b1)
WITH a1, collect(b1.property) AS b1Properties // 2
MATCH (a2:A)-[:R]->(b2:B) // 3
WHERE ID(a1) < ID(a2) // 4
WITH *
ORDER BY ID(b2)
WITH a1, b1Properties, a2, collect(b2.property) AS b2Properties // 5
WHERE b1Properties = b2Properties // 6
RETURN a1, a2, b1Properties, b2Properties // 7
```

Explanation:

1. We query `a1:A`-`b1:B` pairs, sorted by the identifiers of `b1` nodes (to make sure that `b1`s are always in the same order).
2. We collect the `property` values of `b1` nodes to a list `b1Properties`.
3. We do the same for `a2:A`-`b2:B` pairs,
4. but do a filtering for `ID(a1) < ID(a2)` in order to

   - exclude pairs of the same node (e.g. `a6, a6`),
   - exclude duplicate pairs (e.g. `a6, a7` and `a7, a6`).
5. The `property` values of `b2` nodes are sorted and collected to a `b2Properties` list.
6. We only keep results where `b1Properties` and `b2Properties` are equal.
7. We return the results.

The `WITH *` lines are required to use the `ORDER BY` clause, which has to be preceded by a `WITH` or a `RETURN` clause.

The result is:

```
╒══════════╤══════════╤════════════╤════════════╕
│a1        │a2        │b1Properties│b2Properties│
╞══════════╪══════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│{name: a3}│{name: a4}│[p2, p4]    │[p2, p4]    │
├──────────┼──────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│{name: a2}│{name: a5}│[p4]        │[p4]        │
└──────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```